Confusion about Binding in SwiftUI List with ForEach
Issue Description
I'm working on a SwiftUI application and have come across an intriguing issue related to Binding in a ForEach loop within a List. My confusion lies in the way bindings are passed to child views.
Code Example
Here is the working version of my HabitListView, where I use a ForEach to iterate over habitStore.habits. However, I noticed that the binding symbol $ is not used when passing habit to HabitRow and EditHabitView, even though both expect a binding:
struct HabitListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var habitStore: HabitStore
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($habitStore.habits) { habit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditHabitView(habit: habit)) {
                        HabitRow(habit: habit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Interestingly, if I modify the code to include the $ symbol explicitly in the closure and the child views, the program compiles and runs without any issues:
struct HabitListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var habitStore: HabitStore
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($habitStore.habits) { $habit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditHabitView(habit: $habit)) {
                        HabitRow(habit: $habit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Errors on Mixing Binding Symbols
Attempts to mix the usage of binding symbols lead to compile-time errors:

Mixing 01:

Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<[Habit]>' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'
Error: Inferred projection type 'Int' is not a property wrapper

struct HabitListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var habitStore: HabitStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($habitStore.habits) { $habit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditHabitView(habit: habit)) {
                        HabitRow(habit: habit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Mixing 02:

Error: Cannot find '$habit' in scope

struct HabitListView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var habitStore: HabitStore

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            List {
                ForEach($habitStore.habits) { habit in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditHabitView(habit: $habit)) {
                        HabitRow(habit: $habit)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}



Complete views code
EditHabitView
struct EditHabitView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var habitStore: HabitStore
    @State private var draftHabit: Habit
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    init(habit: Binding<Habit>) {
        _draftHabit = State(initialValue: habit.wrappedValue)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Habit name", text: $draftHabit.name)
            TextField("Habit description", text: $draftHabit.description)
            Picker("Select unit", selection: $draftHabit.unit) {
                ForEach(["hours", "reps", "kg", "liters"], id: \.self) { unit in
                    Text(unit)
                }
            }
            .pickerStyle(.wheel)
            Stepper("Counting \(draftHabit.count)", value: $draftHabit.count)
        }
    }
}

HabitRow
struct HabitRow: View {
    @Binding var habit: Habit
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(habit.name).font(.headline)
                Text(habit.description).font(.subheadline)
            }
            Spacer()
            Text("\(habit.count) \(habit.unit)")
            Stepper("", value: $habit.count).labelsHidden()
        }
    }
}

Question
Why does the initial code snippet compile successfully even though HabitRow and EditHabitView supposedly require a Binding<Habit> type, but the habit is passed without using $? Additionally, why does explicitly using $ also work without any issue, and what causes the errors in the mixed scenarios?
GPT answer

The initial snippet works because habit within the ForEach loop is implicitly a Binding<Habit> when you pass ForEach($habitStore.habits). The explicit $ in the loop variable is useful for clarity but not required by the language. Mixing the usage incorrectly introduces syntax and type errors, as Swift cannot reconcile the mixed intentions without explicit direction.
By specifying $habit, you're essentially asking Swift to treat habit as both the original and a binding at the same time, which leads to confusion and errors because by explicity using the binding symbol ($) in the closure arguments, and not using the symbol inside the closure code makes the compiler think that you want to use the non binding version of the argument. And doing the oposite (not using the symbol in the argument but using in the code) impossibilites you from acessing the two versions of the argument.

This look logical, but I couldn't find any sources backing this up.
Can anyone confirm it or correct it?

Fyi $ is just sugar for Binding(get: {}, set: {}) I.e. a pair of closures in a struct.

The overload of ForEach.init that you are using takes a (Binding<C.Element>) -> Content. Therefore, the closure argument would be of type Binding<C.Element>:
ForEach($habitStore.habits) { habit in
    // "habit" is of type Binding<Habit> here
}

This is just how closures normally work. To access the wrappedValue of the binding, you'd have to do habit.wrappedValue.
The proposal SE-0293 enables you to do { $habit in ... }. When you prefix the parameter name with $, $habit is still of type Binding<Habit>, as if $habit is the name of a regular parameter. However, this syntax allows you to access the wrappedValue of $habit just by saying habit. That is, habit would be of type Habit.
ForEach($habitStore.habits) { $habit in
    // "$habit" is of type Binding<Habit> here
    // "habit" is of type Habit, and is the same as "$habit.wrappedValue"
}

So you cannot write { $habit in ... } and then try to use habit as a Binding. If you write { habit in ... }, then $habit does not exist, because habit is not wrapped by a property wrapper, though its type is a property wrapper. This is analogous to the difference between @Binding var foo: String and var foo: Binding<String>. There is no $foo in the latter case.
This closure syntax is only a small part of SE-0293. I recommend reading the whole proposal if you want to see how property wrappers work for function arguments in the general case.

The type of the parameter passed to the ForEach content closure is determined by the type of the collection that ForEach is operating on.
In your case your collection is $habitStore.habits and your closure is therefore receiving a Binding<Habit>.  This means that, in your first code block, habit is a Binding<Habit> and this can be passed to EditHabitView.
Swift uses the $ prefix for implicitly synthesised declarations that are passed to closures.  It is also used to indicate Bindings in SwiftUI, but a $ doesn't implicitly create a binding and not all uses of $ imply a binding.
For example consider:
let someArray = [1,2,3,4]
let incremented = someArray.map { $0 in
   return $0+1
}

$0 is just the argument provided to the closure and is of type Int.  It is not a SwiftUI binding.
You are free to use the $ prefix for implicitly synthesised declarations or not.
In your first code block, you are using habit for the implicity synthesised declaration.
In your second code block you have simply renamed the variable in the ForEach from habit to $habit - The $ doesn't change the type of the variable.  It is a Binding<Habit> either way.
In your "Mixing" code blocks you are getting an error because you have declared the closure parameter as $habit but then refer to an undefined variable habit and vice-versa in the second "Mixing" block.
